# Convert array from Firebase in text message

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I want to create a application  for show text value from Firebase, but i don't exactly know how can show an text from Firebase in my index.

Here is my index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="root">

  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!--FOR ANGULAR JS-->
  <script src="root.js"></script>
  <script src="services.js"></script>
    <!--END ANGULARJS -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap Grid</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />


  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="content">
    <div class="top-content">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 red" >
                  <div ng-controller="root3"><div ng-repeat="message in messages"> {{ message.text }} </div> </div>
          </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my angularJS code:

```
  var root = angular.module('root',["services", "firebase"]);
   root.controller("root",["$scope", "message",function($scope, message) {
       $scope.message = message;
    }]);
    root.controller("root2",["$scope", "message2",function($scope, message){
       $scope.message = message;
    }]);
  root.controller("root3",["$scope", "$firebaseArray", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://web-quickstart-8326d.firebaseio.com");
      var currentMessageRef = rootRef.child('location');
      $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(currentMessageRef);

      var a=1;
  }]);
root.controller("root3",["$scope", "$firebaseArray", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://web-quickstart-8326d.firebaseio.com");
      var currentMessageRef = rootRef.child('location');
      $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(currentMessageRef);

      var a=1;
  }]);
```

Maybe, it's possibile to show value from firebase with `snapshot.val`?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I made an controller look like this and works:

```
root.controller("root3",["$scope", function($scope) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://web-quickstart-8326d.firebaseio.com");
      var currentMessageRef = rootRef.child('location');
      currentMessageRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        $scope.message = snapshot.val();
        $scope.$apply();
      });
  }]);
```

I posted the code for any other user's! Feel free to use it!